# How to grant remote desktop right to a user in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: remote-desktop, permissions, user-accounts, windows-server-2008

I create a user and add it to group `Remote Desktop Users` but I cannot still remote using `mstsc`. The error message said the user/group doesn't have the right to remote.

My question is how can I grant this right to the group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check in the group policy editor (gpedit.msc) under Computer Config > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment. Find the entry for "Allow log on through remote desktop services" and "deny log on through remote desktop services", and see if the groups in question are in either of those categories. Deny permissions will usually override allow permissions.

Answer (score 11):

On the Desktop

Right click Computer > Properties > Remote > Select User > Add > Advance > Find Now >

Select any user and click Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Active directory
1. Go to your domain name
2. Click on user name and go to its property
3. Set its property and give its policy
4. Remove EVERYONE policy and click to ADD and add your username give your created policy to that user