# Server 2012 Essentials Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am having a bit of trouble getting remote desktop to work with some of the other users on my system.

Whenever I try to sign in with an account other than my main one, I get the following error:

```
"To sign in, you need the right to sign in though Remote Desktop Services.".
```

I have tried to install Remote Desktop Services on the server, but that installation fails for some reason.

Does Essentials not support multiple remote desktop users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem in the following post: [How to grant remote desktop right to a user in Windows Server 2008?](https://superuser.com/questions/209204/how-to-grant-remote-desktop-right-to-a-user-in-windows-server-2008).

All I did was add the Remote Desktop Users group to the "Allow log on through remote desktop services" policy, and then add that user group to the users I wanted to give the right to access the server remotely.

Answer (score 1):

On Server 2012 go to the properties of the server, by right clicking on the computer icon and selecting properties. Under the remote desktop tab, and add the users that you want to have access the the server via remote desktop.